# Запуск программы из под root

Tags: linux, сеть, curl, wireshark

Добрый день всем!

Я написал небольшую программку, которая работает с сетью(библиотека `Curl`).

Программа обращается к некоторому хосту и получает от него данные.
Позже, я установил сниффер `WireShark` и после этого моя программа не работает(`Curl` кидает исключение. Говорит о том, что не может подключиться к хосту) от имени моего пользователя.
Программа начинает нормально работать, когда запускаю от имени суперпользователя:

`sudo ./programm`

Такое ощущение, что система блокирует доступ к какому-то системному файлу, к которому обращается `Curl`.

Система `Linux Ubuntu` 17.04.

Можно ли это как-то исправить?
 Дело всё в том, что до установки `WireShark` всё было хорошо.

Comment: а cli curl работает?

Comment: а может просто сайт забанил? все же бывает

Comment: @vp_arth вот что curl говорит в командной строке:
`*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888 failed: В соединении отказано
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: В соединении отказано
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8888: В соединении отказано
`

Comment: @KoVadim нет. Сайт работает) В браузере норм запрос подается)
И говорю же, работает через sudo.

Comment: Покажите `iptables -L`

Comment: @vp_arth 
`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Comment: `telnet 127.0.0.1 8888` из под своего юзера (из под которого не работает) и из под рута? И ещё `ss -tunap | grep 8888`

Comment: @nobody telnet вот что выводит
`Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

ss вообще ничего не выводит

Comment: Дык, это потому что у Вас ничего не слушает порт 8888 полагаю :)

Comment: скорее всего, в браузере оно также не работает (или там просто закешировано/прокси). Так как по урлу локалхост, то для начала я бы проверил, слушает ли кто то нужный порт -  `netstat -nltp` (запускать лучше от рута, будет видно имена процессов). или 127.0.0.1 - это просто обманка, что бы не показывать реальный хост:?

Comment: @nobody @KoVadim
Вот данные, которые выводит ss по обращению через telnet к хосту
`tcp    SYN-SENT   0      1      192.168.2.31:37158              95.173.157.10:8888                users:(("telnet",pid=5366,fd=3))`

Comment: @nobody да нет, вы не поняли. Я делаю коннект по url. Дело не в этом. Всё работает, когда коннект происходит через sudo, а когда от моего имени пытаюсь подключиться, коннект не происходит. Хз почему

Comment: "95.173.157.10" - "The Federal Guard Service of the Russian Federation"... м, я был бы поосторожнее. Но в  любом случае, похоже, Вы пытаетесь обратится к какому то сайту по айпи вместо днс имени. А айпи за днс именем может менятся. И это нормально. Более того, для большинства серверов (http/1.1), если  не указать host в хедерах, то может выдавать дефолтный сайт или ошибку.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо конечно, но меня не это интересует)
Меня интересует почему от имени сеперпользователя получается выполнить запрос, а вот от моего имени - нельзя. )

Comment: есть подозрение, что отличие в прокси. Проксим может быть задано в переменных окружения или файле .curlrc

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо за информацию) Есть куда копать хоть теперь.
По поводу ресурса, то это реестр открытых данных)

Answer (score 1):

> Я написал небольшую программку, которая работает с сетью(библиотека Curl).

Интересно бы знать на чем вы написали программку.

Если **С**, вывод `strace` покажет все обращения программы в пространстве пользователя:

```
~$ strace ./program
```

И смотрим, где она спотыкается.

Если это скрипт на shell, например, **BASH**. Вывод построчного выполнения скрипта, помогает при поиске ошибок:

```
~$ bash -x -c ./program.sh
```

Все запускается под пользователем без привилегий.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно можно вызывать команду при помощи **sudo** передовая ей пароль и оформить это в виде sh файла

```
echo "password" | sudo ./programm
```

но это **не безопасно**...

Comment: только это никак не отвечает на исходный вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim поскольку было описано что с sudo работает то как временное решение возможно подойдет пока не будет выявлена причина такого поведения (не настаиваю на его исключительности и 100% верности). Бывают моменты когда нужно что то срочно запустить, главное что бы работало, а потом уже доводить все до ума.

Comment: я думаю, что человек может выполнить sudo -s

Comment: @KoVadim естественно может если запускает в ручную, а если запуск должен происходить автоматически то это будет уже проблемно...